# Is "Alaric's Gift" set in the same universe as "The Legend of Nightfall"?

Tags: mickey-zucker-reichert

I recently ran into [Fantasy short story with soul-taking magic users](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/fantasy-short-story-with-soul-taking-magic-users) again, which cited as an answer "Alaric's Gift" by Mickey Zucker Reichert. I had a comment about how I'd initially assumed that they were referring to *The Legend of Nightfall* by the same author, which had a similar concept that some people had magical talents that could be stolen by "sorcerers" and it's now bugging me a bit. Are they meant to be in the same universe? I haven't found any proof either way so far. I have sent a message via [the author's website](http://mickeyzuckerreichert.com/), but has anyone else found a reference as to whether the works are connected?